# Как перезапускать скрипт до того момента пока ошибка TypeError не уйдет?

Tags: python, windows, while, type-error, event-loop

```
x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(path, confidence = 0.8)

pyautogui.moveTo(x,y,duration=1)
pyautogui.click(x,y,interval=0.05)
```

Comment: try - except вам в помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```py
while True:
    try:
        x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(path, confidence = 0.8)

        pyautogui.moveTo(x,y,duration=1)
        pyautogui.click(x,y,interval=0.05)

        break
    except TypeError:
        continue
```